# Applets and liftweb in scala

Tags: scala, applet, lift

My goal is to create an applet on a client machine which somehow is able to communicate back and forth with the same server that deployed the applet. One way of doing this would of course be through some kind of AJAX code, but if it's possible I'd very much like to keep everything in Scala.

So far I've used remote actors which have the unfortunate consequence that the applet needs to be signed. Which isn't an optimal solution either. I'm searching for alternate solutions.

Is there any way to make an applet deployed by liftweb communicate with lift directly via Scala?

Answer (score 1):

Communication through remote actors *is* directly via Scala.

Now, Lift enables one to run *JavaScript* code on the client, communicating with the Scala server seamlessly (and without having to write a single line of JavaScript code). See the many Lift examples for that (for instance, the wizard).

Comment: So basically you're saying that there aren't any way to communicate through scala without signing the applet and using remote actors?

Comment: @Jens I had said no such thing. Scala will, of course, have all the same restrictions any other applet has. If an applet cannot open a socket without being signed, then no applet can talk to the server without being signed, no matter what language they were written in.

Comment: @Daniel C. Sobral: *"If an applet cannot open a socket without being signed.."*  The JRE will allow a sand-boxed applet to open sockets, so long as the applet is 'phoning home' to it's own server.